# How to find a subdifferential of $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto |x_1 + x_2| + |x_1 - x_2|$?

Tags: subgradient, non-smooth-analysis

I know that function $x \mapsto |x|$  has the following subdifferential

$$\partial f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
     1   &, x>0 \\
[-1,1]   &, x=0 \\
    -1   &, x<0.
\end{cases}$$

for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. However, I have no idea how to find the subdifferential of

$$(x_1, x_2) \mapsto |x_1 + x_2| + |x_1 - x_2|$$

I tried to consider the subdifferential of $|x_1 + x_2|$ but I still failed to find it. If you have any ideas on how to find the subdifferential, please share them with me. Thank you.